# moveit_setup_assistant how to choose chain, joint and link for planning group

Tags: ros, joint, moveit-setup-assistant

[image: Rosanswers logo]

**BACKGROUND**

In [moveit_setup_assistant tutorial](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/moveit_tutorials/html/doc/setup_assistant/setup_assistant_tutorial.html), in **planning group** section, it tells that click **joint** button to choose joints for **right_arm**. I did this and followed all the procedure as the tutorial tells.

However, when trying to roslaunch the **demo.launch** from **pr2_moveit_config** I generated, I found that the **interactive marker** was **missing** in **rviz**.

I searched for solution in ros answer and found that they said it might be **either end effector or parent link of end effector undefined**. I checked my config setup for pr2, however, actually **all were set as the tutorial asks**.

Then, I turned to the **book, ros-by-example V2, CH11**, which introduces moveit, where configuring planning group for pi robot, it **edit chain for right_arm instead of editing joint**.

So I modified **chain** section and deleted **joint** section for **right_arm group** for **pr2**.

It turned out that **interactive marker appeared finally**, and worked well.

**QUESTION**

What are meant by **chain**, **joint** and **link** for **planning group in moveit setup**, respectively?

When might one choose **chain** or **joint** for **arm**?

When should one choose **link** or/and **joint** for **end effector**?

---

In book, **Master ROS for Robotics Programming**
Here is the setting for **planning group**, where it sets **chain** for **arm** and **both joint and link for gripper**( instead, the above 2 tutorial **only set link for gripper**).
[image: image description]

---

In conclusion, 3 tutorials **set planning group differently**, why?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/252036/moveit_setup_assistant-how-to-choose-chain,-joint-and-link-for-planning-group/) by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 339 on 2017-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi Shawnysh,

`Joints`, `Links`, `Chains` and `Subgroups` represent different ways that you can use to specify which parts of the robot (as specified in the URDF) are part of your current planning group.

Looking at the [srdf wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/srdf), you can find some more information on the different types. For instance, notice that when a joint is added,  the child link is automatically also included.

A chain is just an easy way to add several joints and links to the srdf without having to manually select all the joints/links in between. It is not advisable to mix different methods in a single group.

Hope that clears things up a bit.

---

Originally posted by [rbbg](https://answers.ros.org/users/26757/rbbg/) with karma: 1823 on 2017-01-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shawnysh](https://answers.ros.org/users/28421/shawnysh/) on 2017-01-16**:
It is a great explanation to my questions, thanks for your kindness,.